# Deploying SDK Addon component

Tags: android, sdk, add-on, deploying

Based on PlatformLibrary sample code in the SDK, I have created a small hello world library, the eventual goal of the library is to add capability for 3rd part developers to develop for my custom Android image.
I am currently stuck at the point on how to deploy the same so that developers can start using it, I am unable to find any pointers, please help if you have any information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured out based on for 4.0.3

1. Create a new sample device, based on the the existing one located at

   ```
   <SDK-ROOT>/device/sample
   ```
2. build the sdk-addon

   ```
   <SDK-ROOT>$ . build/envsetup.sh
   <SDK-ROOT>$ make -j8 PRODUCT-<your-sdk-addon-name>-sdk_addon
   ```
3. Once the SDK is build you will get the sdk addon archive located at

   ```
   <SDK-ROOT>/out/host/linux-x86/sdk-addon/<sdkname>.zip
   ```
4. I copied the ZIP to the http server directory, so that it has a link I can refer in Android SDK manager.
5. Created new SDK XML configuration file and put it in the http server (I used the one located at http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml for reference)
6. Went to Android SDK manager, added path to new add on XML created on #5 and OK
7. Install the new SDK On listed in the android SDK manager, after the installation is done, you can get check the add-ons directory of ur developer SDK to find the add-on.

Also bits and pieces from marakana.com/s/remixing_android,1044/index.html helped.

Comment: hi hack, thanks for this infoemation , i go thru marakana.com/ ...but here he missed lot information..do u have any other refernece related to create+build sdk add-ons.

Comment: What information are you missing? probably you can post a detailed question on SO, most of the stuff is not documented properly or not available easily (difficult to search for) I had to reverse engineer lots of stuff to understand this, http://androidxref.com/ should be your starting point, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you resolved your own issue, but just FYI - to simplify/automate your step #5 above, you can use the mk_sdk_repo_xml.sh script provided under platform/development/build/tools to build the add-on repository.

This is actually used by the phony 'sdk_repo' target (platform/development/build/tools/sdk_repo.mk), so you can take a look to see what the intended usage is. It has the benefit of managing all the packaging/checksum generation etc for you.

Note that it's supposed to provide some automagic behaviour based on the ADDON_SDK_ZIP which is defined by the sdk_addon build task, but that never worked on our customized gingerbread platform, so I ended up putting in an explicit call like this:

```
$(shell $(TOPDIR)development/build/tools/mk_sdk_repo_xml.sh \
    $(TOPDIR)out/host/linux-x86/sdk_addon/addon.xml \
    $(TOPDIR)sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/repository/sdk-addon-1.xsd \
    add-on any $(TOPDIR)out/host/linux-x86/sdk_addon/LIBRARY_NAME-eng-linux-x86.zip:sdk-repo-any-addon-LIBRARY_NAME.zip )
```

Answer (score 2):

**I figured out based on 4.4.2 and Andrdoid Studio 1.4, and it doesn't need put sdk add on xml to web server.**

1.Create a new sample device, based on the the existing one located at

```
<ANDROID-ROOT>/device/<your-sdk-addon-name>
```

2.build the sdk-addon

```
<ANDROID-ROOT>$ . build/envsetup.sh
<ANDROID-ROOT>$ make -j8 PRODUCT-<your-sdk-addon-name>-sdk_addon
```

3.Once the SDK is build you will get the sdk addon archive located at

```
<ANDROID-ROOT>/out/host/linux-x86/sdk-addon/<sdkname>.zip
```

4.Extract .zip to

```
<SDK-ROOT>\add-ons\<your-sdk-addon-name>
```

5.Copy

```
<ANDROID-ROOT>\device\<your-sdk-addon-name>\sdk_addon\manifest.ini
```

to

```
<SDK-ROOT>\add-ons\<your-sdk-addon-name>
```

6. Create new file source.properties to `<SDK-ROOT>\add-ons\<your-sdk-addon-name>`

   Addon.NameId=**your-sdk-addon-name**

   Pkg.Desc=Provides the oem APIs to 3rd party apk developer

   Addon.VendorId=**your-sdk-addon-vendor-name**

   Archive.Arch=ANY

   Addon.NameDisplay=**your-sdk-addon-name**

   Addon.VendorDisplay=**your-sdk-addon-vendor-name**

   Archive.Os=ANY

   Pkg.Revision=1

   AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=19
7. Open SDK Manager, your will see your SDK add on listed
8. New a Android Studio project, edit build.gradle file:

   ```
   android {

       compileSdkVersion "<your-sdk-addon-vendor-name>:<your-sdk-addon-name>:<sdk-api-level>"

       ...
   }
   ```
9. Build the project, your add on jar will be loaded to External Libraries in Android Studio

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification: <your-sdk-addon-vendor-name>, <your-sdk-addon-name> and <sdk-api-level> are all defined in the 'manifest.ini' file inside the addon zip package (name, vendor, api).