# In Androird how to expose a library API in AOSP to 3rd party developers

Tags: android, api, android-source

So I want to do the following

1) Build a internal library inside the AOSP system that exposes some features of the internal Android system
2) Turn this into a third party library.

So the problem is, if I just go and add some classes to core java framework and make the API public it does not help because the third party developer can not build against it.

So what else needs to be done so that developer can access my API ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this problem solved?.Are you able to generate the sdk which include the new classes written in aosp?.

Please suggest on this. I have same requirement.

Comment: is this work for you?
I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> So what else needs to be done so that developer can access my API ?

Build your own ROM mod that contains your revised AOSP code. Ideally, package those changes and the corresponding SDK-style code as [an SDK add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598782/deploying-sdk-addon-component). Then, developers can use your revisions on devices that are running your ROM mod.

Answer (score 1):

After adding additional functionality to `AOSP` follow next steps:

1) add your classes to `AOSP API`

```
make update-api
```

2) compile `Android SDK` from `AOSP`

```
make PRODUCT-sdk-sdk
```

**Result:** You have compiled `Android SDK` in `out/host/linux-x86/sdk/`